# Insert into a table with a mix of dynamic and static data from a text file

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

I have two tables like as given below

**condition** (text file stored as table).

```
SNO   Subject_id   
1        A1        
2        A2        
3        A3         
4        A4
```

**Observation**

```
Id   subject_id     START_DATE   END_DATE
1      D1           21/01/2007   21/01/2017
1      D2           23/05/1998   23/05/2008
1      D3           13/04/2017   13/04/2020
```

I expect my output be like below. As you can see, except the `subject_id` column which comes from text file(stored as condition table) but rest of the columns `(Id, START_DATE, END_DATE)` are static and same

```
Id   subject_id     START_DATE   END_DATE
1      D1           21/01/2007   21/01/2017
1      D2           23/05/1998   23/05/2008
1      D3           13/04/2017   13/04/2020
2      A1           01/01/2000   01/01/2010 
2      A2           01/01/2000   01/01/2010 
2      A3           01/01/2000   01/01/2010 
2      A4           01/01/2000   01/01/2010
```

This is what I tried but couldn't get the expected output as `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` are mandatory for observation table.

```
insert into observation (Id,subject_id,start_date,end_date)
select '2',subject_id,'01/01/2000','01/01/2010' from condition;
```

Can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a union:

```
SELECT Id, subject_id, START_DATE, END_DATE FROM Observation
UNION ALL
SELECT '2', subject_id, '01/01/2000', '01/01/2010' FROM condition
ORDER BY Id, subject_id;
```

If you really want the observation table to look like your expected output, then your current insert is actually correct.

Comment: I get an error like this `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "distinct"
LINE 1: SELECT '2', distinct person_id, '01/01/2000', '01/01/2010' F...
                    ^`

Comment: Then you're not running my code, because I never used `DISTINCT` anywhere.

Comment: Okay, the thing is sometimes the subject_ids might be duplicate. So I used Distinct

Comment: Can you let me know how to use Distinct in a case like this? I know you told my insert query would work which it does but when there are duplicates, even that throws an error

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with distinct, but the syntax is off.  You might want to open a new question at this point.